# A working stack allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stack

Here's an absolutely essential piece of C++ lore, a stack allocator, that will allow you to, say, allocate strings and vectors on the stack. There are 2 stack allocators I know of, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783944/how-do-i-allocate-a-stdstring-on-the-stack-using-glibcs-string-implementation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648202/questions-about-hinnants-stack-allocator).

The trouble was, neither of them were working with gcc-4.8, and both needed fixing. Here's a fixed version of Hinant's allocator. Could there some improvement or fix to still be made?

```
#pragma once
#ifndef STACKALLOCATOR_HPP
# define STACKALLOCATOR_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <cstddef>

#include <functional>

#include <new>

#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N>
class stack_store
{
public:
  stack_store() = default;

  stack_store(stack_store const&) = delete;

  stack_store& operator=(stack_store const&) = delete;

  char* allocate(std::size_t n)
  {
    assert(pointer_in_buffer(ptr_) &&
      "stack_allocator has outlived stack_store");

    n = align(n);

    if (buf_ + N >= ptr_ + n)
    {
      auto r(ptr_);

      ptr_ += n;

      return r;
    }
    else
    {
      return static_cast<char*>(::operator new(n));
    }
  }

  void deallocate(char* const p, std::size_t n) noexcept
  {
    assert(pointer_in_buffer(ptr_) &&
      "stack_allocator has outlived stack_store");

    if (pointer_in_buffer(p))
    {
      n = align(n);

      if (p + n == ptr_)
      {
        ptr_ = p;
      }
      // else do nothing
    }
    else
    {
      ::operator delete(p);
    }
  }

  void reset() noexcept { ptr_ = buf_; }

  static constexpr ::std::size_t size() noexcept { return N; }

  ::std::size_t used() const { return ::std::size_t(ptr_ - buf_); }

private:
  static constexpr ::std::size_t align(::std::size_t const n) noexcept
  {
    return (n + (alignment - 1)) & -alignment;
  }

  bool pointer_in_buffer(char* const p) noexcept
  {
    return (buf_ <= p) && (p <= buf_ + N);
  }

private:
  static constexpr auto const alignment = alignof(::max_align_t);

  char* ptr_{buf_};

  alignas(::max_align_t) char buf_[N];
};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class stack_allocator
{
public:
  using store_type = stack_store<N>;

  using size_type = ::std::size_t;

  using difference_type = ::std::ptrdiff_t;

  using pointer = T*;
  using const_pointer = T const*;

  using reference = T&;
  using const_reference = T const&;

  using value_type = T;

  template <class U> struct rebind { using other = stack_allocator<U, N>; };

  stack_allocator() = default;

  stack_allocator(stack_store<N>& s) noexcept : store_(&s) { }

  template <class U>
  stack_allocator(stack_allocator<U, N> const& other) noexcept :
    store_(other.store_)
  {
  }

  stack_allocator& operator=(stack_allocator const&) = delete;

  T* allocate(::std::size_t const n)
  {
    return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(
      store_->allocate(n * sizeof(T))));
  }

  void deallocate(T* const p, ::std::size_t const n) noexcept
  {
    store_->deallocate(static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(p)),
      n * sizeof(T));
  }

  template <class U, class ...A>
  void construct(U* const p, A&& ...args)
  {
    new (p) U(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <class U>
  void destroy(U* const p)
  {
    p->~U();
  }

  template <class U, std::size_t M>
  inline bool operator==(stack_allocator<U, M> const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return store_ == rhs.store_;
  }

  template <class U, std::size_t M>
  inline bool operator!=(stack_allocator<U, M> const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return !(*this == rhs);
  }

private:
  template <class U, std::size_t M> friend class stack_allocator;

  store_type* store_{};
};

namespace std
{
  // string
  template<class CharT> class char_traits;

  template<class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator> class basic_string;

  // unordered_map
  template<class Key, class T, class Hash, class Pred, class Alloc>
    class unordered_map;

  // vector
  template <class T, class Alloc> class vector;
}

using stack_string = ::std::basic_string<char, ::std::char_traits<char>,
  stack_allocator<char, 128> >;

template <class Key, class T, class Hash = ::std::hash<Key>,
  class Pred = ::std::equal_to<Key> >
using stack_unordered_map = ::std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, Pred,
  stack_allocator<::std::pair<Key const, T>, 256> >;

template <typename T>
using stack_vector = ::std::vector<T, stack_allocator<T, 256> >;

#endif // STACKALLOCATOR_HPP
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stackallocator.hpp"

int main()
{
  ::stack_string::allocator_type::store_type s;

  ::std::cout << ::stack_string("blabla", s).c_str() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

After running the above example under valgrind, it will report:

> ```
> ==25600== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==25600==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==25600==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
> ==25600== 
> ==25600== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
> ==25600== 
> ==25600== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==25600== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
> ```

Comment: Why do you use global namespacing operator `::` in example usage?

Comment: @sasha.sochka It's not really a global operator, it just means outside of the current namespace.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need it?

Comment: @sasha.sochka It's slightly more pedantic to use it than not. Programming is conveying meaning to the compiler. If you write `::stack_string`, you mean exactly that, a `::stack_string` type outside the current namespace.

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote this because the question lacks enough detail to be answerable. You should rephrase your question by adding more detail what exactly does not work out of the box with Hinnant's allocator, and which uses cases you want to support. It's an interesting problem to consider and I encourage you to spend more effort on it to help potential readers.

Comment: @TemplateRex I think you mistook Code Review for SO. I wasn't asking for help in compiling Hinant's allocator, but for suggestions/fixes for my fix. We're commenting code here, not asking for help in making code work.

Comment: @TemplateRex Here's a little something to prove my point: http://ideone.com/VzzS4I I think you're not providing useful advice.

Comment: I understand the difference between code review and answering questions. When you write "Trouble was neither of them was working with gcc-4.8, both needed fixing." and provide a long and renamed implementation of Hinnant's stack allocator, it is hard to see why all those changes were necessary. At the very least you could have provided a summary of the types of errors (simple warnings, missing typedefs / members, missing constructors) that you got without your fixes. Reviewing fixes without a rationale (other than "was not working") for those fixes is rather hard, IMO.

Comment: @TemplateRex Hinant himself hinted improvements might be possible here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648202/questions-about-hinnants-stack-allocator , but did not do so. The thing is, I pasted in code - without it my post would have been invalid - and you can suggest improvements based on that alone. You don't need to know about history of the code or anything else. The code compiles and the question was how to improve it. The implementation was not renamed, I gave due credit.

Comment: Look, reasonable people can disagree here, but I am used to reviewing fixes by 3 measures: a) was it broken before, and if so, how? b) does the fix actually correct these problems? and c) is the patch as unintrusive as possible? All these aspects require at least more background about the nature of the problem that you are trying to fix.

Comment: @TemplateRex I was asking about the things Hinant hinted of, for example, the fix works for me. I cannot ask that sort of thing on SO. This is the place for that.

Comment: Doesn't the allocator need to use `stack_store<sizeof(T) * N>;` ?

Comment: Don't know, if you are still monitoring this, but your `pointer_in_buffer` function exhibits undefined behavior, if the pointer doesn't point into the buffer. I'd recommend using STL - compare objects and leave a comment in the code, about why you did that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766570/how-do-i-safely-and-sensibly-determine-whether-a-pointer-points-somewhere-into-a

Comment: @MikeMB Thanks! Fortunately the fix is very easy.

Comment: @user1095108: Appears I was wrong - Sorry for that. I brought up the same topic on TemplateRex's original question about Hinnant's allocator and he explained, that in C++ (contrary to C) it is actually not undefined, but unspecified (read implementation dependent) behavior. So if your are not targeting a particular stange platform, the solution with the standard operators should also be fine

Comment: @user1095108 If you're in nested namespaces and each has the symbol  `x` in it, then `::x`will bring you to the global `x`, not the `x` from the closest outside namespace.  Compared to filesystem navigation `::` is like `/` not like `..`.

Answer (score 8):

### Fixes required for a conforming Standard Library

There is one big issue that will make custom allocators fragile to work with: incomplete C++11 library support. Since C++11, containers are required to go through `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>` to access `construct()` and `destroy()` allocator member functions, as well as to access nested typedefs such as `pointer` and `reference`. Furthermore, all containers have a constructor with a single allocator argument. Not every Standard Library implements this for every container.

With the [Coliru online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), I can get [Hinnant's stack allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) working with `libstdc++` for a `std::vector` with only 2 minor modifications running

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O1 -pedantic -Wall -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo
```

The first is to put parenthesis around the `n + (alignment - 1)` operand in the `align_up()`

```
std::size_t 
    align_up(std::size_t n) noexcept
        {return (n + (alignment-1)) & ~(alignment-1);}
                ^                 ^
```

The second is to remove the exception specification from the overloaded `operator new`

```
void* operator new(std::size_t s) // throw(std::bad_alloc)
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d69fbdac7f2c9b4c) exactly reproducing [Hinnant's first test case](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html).

Note that these 2 warnings are rather innocent and do not affect correctness of the program.

### Fixes required for a non-conforming Standard Library

Since `libstdc++` works fine with all containers if a `std::allocator` is provided (even when the container implementation directly accesses the allocator, rather than through `std::allocator_traits`) the safest bet is to provide all the nested typedefs and member functions of `std::allocator_traits` in your own allocator as well. This includes the various pointer and reference types, as well as the rebind templates. You appear to have done so, and this should resolve at least of all those issues. I still would leave the original naming of Hinnant's version in tact, though.

That leaves the issues of constructors taking a single allocator argument. At least for `libstdc++` for g++ 4.8.1, [this constructor is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18913388/819272) for `std:unordered_map`. Apart from patching the standard library headers yourself (possible, but if you have an automatic package updater, that will require constant monitoring) or [submit a bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/appendix_contributing.html). Microsoft did have many such issues in Visual C++ 2012 November CTP, which have all been fixed in Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: Try making it work with an `unordered_map`. This was the source of major problems. Even so, it did not work out of the box.

Comment: @user1095108 It does work out-of-the-box without `-Wall`. Simply fixing the warnings as I showed above also works. What exactly does not work with `std::unordered_map`? And please indicate how I could improve this answer (if you were the one downvoting it).

Comment: In my case it had a problem with the lack of a default constructor. Even if you added one, the compiler complained about a dangling reference. The problem, I think, had to do with `libstdc++`'s `std::string` implementation. Are you interested in seeing the error? In general you need to adapt the allocator to the situation at hand, sometimes, the STL container is odd itself (for example, does not make use of ::std::allocator_traits). I downvoted because you are not providing fixes/thoughts for improvement.

Comment: @user1095108 I think the problems you have with `std::unordered_map` and custom allocators are related to incomplete `libstdc++` support for constructors taking a single allocator argument, and are unrelated to this specific allocator version. FYI, I posed a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18913388/819272) on SO about it.

Comment: @user1095108 I think your downvoting is rather harsh. I answered in detail how 2 minor fixes would eliminate the (innocent!) warnings from Hinnant's stack allocator. You then respond by making up 2 use cases that do not appear in your original question. How is one going to answer that without more detail?

Comment: I did not ask about fixing the Hinant's allocator, since I've fixed it myself. I was asking about fixes to my fix. I don't care if my question gets downvoted to -inf, so why do you care if I downvote your answer?

Comment: @user1095108 My fixes to your fix are detailed in my answer: roll them all back (you are providing way too much, e.g. `construct()` / `destroy()`) and apply the 2 tiny fixes I showed you.

Comment: Your suggestion is wrong, because of the oddities of libstdc++'s implementation of `unordered_map`. I.e. it does not use `::std::allocator_traits` for `construct`/`destroy`. The tiny fixes don't apply to my fix.

Comment: @user1095108 I have taken your comments into account, see updated answer. Your fixes are fine, and they will resolve the issue of direct allocator accesses (rather than through `std::allocator_traits`. For missing constructors, you cannot do much except patch the library headers or submitting a bug report (which I would encourage you to do so regardless).

Comment: I'll remove the downvote, but I won't accept just yet, since I was hoping for some fine hacks on top of those already provided.

Comment: @user1095108 I don't think you can "hack" a missing constructor, other than adding it into the libstdc++ source yourself. I feel your pain, having gone through the Visual C++ headers myself this way, last year.

Comment: Note Howard's old pages are gone, so you need to update those links: http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour tnx, updated!